# Creating 'n' combinations randomly from multiple lists

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

```
def models():
    default = [0.6,0.67,2.4e-2,1e-2,2e-5,1.2e-3,2e-5]
    lower = [np.log10(i/10) for i in default]
    upper = [np.log10(i*10) for i in default]
    n = 5
    a = np.logspace(lower[0],upper[0],n)
    b = np.logspace(lower[1],upper[1],n)
    c = np.logspace(lower[2],upper[2],n)
    d = np.logspace(lower[3],upper[3],n)
    e = np.logspace(lower[4],upper[4],n)
    f = np.logspace(lower[5],upper[5],n)
    g = np.logspace(lower[6],upper[6],n)

    combs = itertools.product(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

    list1 = []

    for x in combs:
        x = list(x)
        list1.append(x)


    return list1
```

The code above returns a list of 5^7 = 78,125 lists. Is there a way I can combine items in a,b,c,d,e,f,g, possibly randomly, to create a list of say, 10000, lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take random samples of each array and combine them, especially if you don't need to guarantee that specific combinations don't occur more than once:

```
import numpy as np
import random


def random_models(num_values):
    n = 5
    default = [0.6, 0.67, 2.4e-2, 1e-2, 2e-5, 1.2e-3, 2e-5]
    ranges = zip((np.log10(i/10) for i in default),
                 (np.log10(i*10) for i in default))

    data_arrays = []
    for lower, upper in ranges:
        data_arrays.append(np.logspace(lower, upper, n))

    results = []

    for i in xrange(num_values):
        results.append([random.choice(arr) for arr in data_arrays])

    return results


l = random_models(10000)
print len(l)
```

Here's a version that will avoid repeats up until you request more data than can be given without repeating:

```
def random_models_avoid_repeats(num_values):
    n = 5
    default = [0.6, 0.67, 2.4e-2, 1e-2, 2e-5, 1.2e-3, 2e-5]

    # Build the range data (tuples of (lower, upper) range)
    ranges = zip((np.log10(i/10) for i in default),
                 (np.log10(i*10) for i in default))

    # Create the data arrays to sample from
    data_arrays = []
    for lower, upper in ranges:
        data_arrays.append(np.logspace(lower, upper, n))

    sequence_data = []
    for entry in itertools.product(*data_arrays):
        sequence_data.append(entry)

    results = []

    # Holds the current choices to choose from.  The data will come from
    # sequence_data above, but randomly shuffled.  Values are popped off the
    # end to keep things efficient.  It's possible to ask for more data than
    # the samples can give without repeats.  In that case, we'll reload
    # temp_data, randomly shuffle again, and start the process over until we've
    # delivered the number of desired results.
    temp_data = []
    # Build the lists
    for i in xrange(num_values):
        if len(temp_data) == 0:
            temp_data = sequence_data[:]
            random.shuffle(temp_data)
        results.append(temp_data.pop())

    return results
```

Also note that we can avoid building a results list if you make this a generator by using `yield`.  However, you'd want to consume the results using a `for`statement as well:

```
def random_models_avoid_repeats_generator(num_values):
    n = 5
    default = [0.6, 0.67, 2.4e-2, 1e-2, 2e-5, 1.2e-3, 2e-5]

    # Build the range data (tuples of (lower, upper) range)
    ranges = zip((np.log10(i/10) for i in default),
                 (np.log10(i*10) for i in default))

    # Create the data arrays to sample from
    data_arrays = []
    for lower, upper in ranges:
        data_arrays.append(np.logspace(lower, upper, n))

    sequence_data = []
    for entry in itertools.product(*data_arrays):
        sequence_data.append(entry)

    # Holds the current choices to choose from.  The data will come from
    # sequence_data above, but randomly shuffled.  Values are popped off the
    # end to keep things efficient.  It's possible to ask for more data than
    # the samples can give without repeats.  In that case, we'll reload
    # temp_data, randomly shuffle again, and start the process over until we've
    # delivered the number of desired results.
    temp_data = []
    # Build the lists
    for i in xrange(num_values):
        if len(temp_data) == 0:
            temp_data = sequence_data[:]
            random.shuffle(temp_data)
        yield temp_data.pop()
```

You'd have to use it like this:

```
for entry in random_models_avoid_repeats_generator(10000):
    # Do stuff...
```

Or manually iterate over it using `next()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way I can make sure that specific combinations do not occur more than once? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on what you're willing to give up.  Make sure there are no duplicates but providing random samples involves either generating the whole list and removing random samples to form the new list, or keeping state as to what has been delivered already with some extra logic to know that you've exhausted the full supply.  Are you willing to use the memory for such an endeavor?  If so, then I can update the answer to do it.

Comment: Yes, please. Thank you so much.